# Backup a database onto a different destination server

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

We have two development environments: `Development` server and `Test` server. Both of these servers are linked. I need to backup a particular database from `test` server.

The problem is: I have access only to the `development` server location (only development server location is visible on the network). When I took backup of the database it got saved on `Test` server. Because of this, I couldn't get the backup file.

My question: is it possible to take the backup of a database on one server with another server as destination path?

Comment: As long as the **destination path** is an UNC path (`\\otherserver\sqlserverbackups`) and the account which the SQL Server on your first server has **write access** to that remote UNC path - then yes